# Can't take snapshot of the browser

Tags: qtp

When I run the code below in QTP, an error message `Invalid procedure call or argument` appears

```
Browser("micClass:=Browser").CaptureBitmap "D:\SnapShots", False
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `.png` or `.bmp` extension while specifying the file name for the snapshot.
The following should work:

```
Browser("micClass:=Browser").CaptureBitmap "D:\SnapShots.png", False
```

If "D:\SnapShots" is a folder, please specify the filename, something like below:

```
Browser("micClass:=Browser").CaptureBitmap "D:\SnapShots\snapshot1.png", False
```